# Django - How to filter a ManyToMany model object?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following models which are linked via a foreign key and ManyToMany relationship.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class AssetMetadata(models.Model):

    id = models.DecimalField(6).auto_creation_counter
    material_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    series_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    season_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    season_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    episode_title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    episode_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    synopsis = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    ratings = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.material_id

class Batch(models.Model):
    material_id = models.ManyToManyField(AssetMetadata)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Batch_' + str(self.pk) + '_' + self.user.username
```

I can see that this has worked and the models have been created and the relationships work as you would expect. As you can see from the console output:

```
>>> from asset_db.models import Batch
>>> Batch.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'user_id': 1, 'id': 1}, {'user_id': 3, 'id': 2}]>
```

When i migrated the models it created the following tables (added so you can see the relationships).

asset_db_batch:

```
id | user_id
____________
1  |    1
2  |    3
```

asset_db_batch_material_id:

```
id    |   batch_id  |  assetmetadata_id
______|_____________|________________
1     |      1      |        1
2     |      1      |        2
3     |      1      |        6
4     |      1      |        8
5     |      1      |        4
6     |      2      |        8
7     |      2      |        2
8     |      2      |        4
9     |      2      |        7
```

My question is how do I filter the `Batch` object to return the items associated to a `batch_id`? Basically how do i recreate this SQL query in Django:

```
SELECT * FROM asset_db_batch_material_id
  INNER JOIN asset_db_batch
    ON asset_db_batch_material_id.batch_id = asset_db_batch.id
  INNER JOIN asset_db_assetmetadata
    ON asset_db_batch_material_id.assetmetadata_id = asset_db_assetmetadata.id
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how you do with ForeignKey

```
AssetMetadata.objects.filter(batch__user__id=1)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. It's understanding the filter syntax that I am having issues with, Can you recommend any useful resources which explain this is more detail?

Comment: Can't think of anything off and. My rule is "when in doubt always try `__`"

Comment: I am sure you have seen this, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships  yes, it's forgettable.

Comment: Yep, it was the order of words between the `__` and the keywords like `contains` which i found confusing.